# behavior of declarations in async mode nodejs

Tags: node.js

consider the below code:

```
function printVariable(variable){
    variable++;
    console.log(variable);
}
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var i = 1;
var j = 2;
var k = 3;
printVariable(i);// [1]
printVariable(j);// [2]
printVariable(k);// [3]
var i = 6;       // [4]
printVariable(i);// [5]
```

the output is:

```
2
3
4
7
```

As I know nodejs is a async javascript platform by default.

Is it possible the [5] call runs before [4]? then the last line of output will be 2? or [1] call logs 1 to console?

if it runs for example 20000 time per second, Will it guarantees declarations' order?

in another hand, is it possible declarations did not runs in sync?

Comment: There's nothing async about your code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js isn't a language. JavaScript is a language.

Node.js is a platform allowing the execution of Javascript code and making it easy to call asynchronous operations (most often IO related operations). The idea being that your functions are called on events, node managing the event queue and underlying operations (which might be executed in parallel).

But there's always only ONE thread executing your code.

Your code, which doesn't defer any execution, is totally synchronous and will always produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not the language it is the platfrom.

Talking about your code it is the basic JS code and 
you are reassigning the value to `i,j,k` as JS is the interpenetrated language it takes the latest value.
So when you call the **printVariable** function it took 1,2,3 as input.

If you want to learn Async concept in JS watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Being interpreted has nothing to do with it.